# How to make a concrete secondary constructor in Kotlin, when the primary constructor is generic?

Tags: generics, kotlin, constructor

I'm trying to figure out how to make a secondary constructor for a generic class, so I can essentially create a "default" version of it easily. This code seems reasonable to me - the secondary constructor calls the primary one with a concrete T: Table. But the compiler doesn't seem to recognise this, giving "Type mismatch: inferred type is Scratch_5.Furniture.table but T was expected" for the secondary constructor.

```
sealed class Furniture {
    class NamedChair(name: String) : Furniture()
    object Table : Furniture()
}

class Blah<T : Furniture>(
    data: T
) {
    constructor() : this(Furniture.Table)
}

var blah = Blah(Furniture.Table)
var equalBlah = Blah()
```

However, the `var blah = Blah(Furniture.Table)` line using the primary constructor works perfectly fine. Is there anything I'm missing here? How would I modify this to have it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a concrete secondary constructor while the primary has a generic parameter.

However you can achieve the same effect with a little trick using the `operator fun invoke()` on `Blah`:

```kotlin
class Blah<T : Furniture>(data: T) {
  companion object {
    operator fun invoke(): Blah<Furniture.Table> = Blah(Furniture.Table)
  }
}
```

Or you can use a `fun` named `Blah` (thanks to @AlexeyRomanov):

```kotlin
fun Blah(): Blah<Furniture.Table> = Blah(Furniture.Table)
```

Now you can successfully call:

```kotlin
var blah = Blah(Furniture.Table)
// Calls the invoke operator fun which invokes the primary constructor.
var equalBlah = Blah()
```

Comment: Or just `fun Blah(): Blah<Furniture.Table> = Blah(Furniture.Table)`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Yes, this is another valid solution, I'm editing my answer adding yours too, thanks!